# How to aggregate values in a pyspark dataframe without grouping by and excluding rows Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe like this

```
A | B | C
1 | 1 | 'a'
2 | 1 | 'b'
3 | 1 | 'c'
4 | 2 | 'd'
5 | 2 | 'e'
6 | 2 | 'f'
```

I want to do in way that i can do a filter, like chose a especific row, and group the values for the rows with same id, example, suppose I filter for the row 1 and 4 and run the group, i want something just like this

```
A | B | C
1 | 1 | ['a','b','c']
2 | 1 | 'b'
3 | 1 | 'c'
4 | 2 | ['d','e','f']
5 | 2 | 'e'
6 | 2 | 'f'
```

where i aggregate the values of column c that hasve the same value on column B

PS: the filter part is not the problem, i just want the transformation where i iterate over the dataframe and collect the values for same ID

PS 2: i am using spark 2.4

Comment: In Spark you cannot have multiple datatypes in the same column, in your example C is string and array[string]. Either have all array or all string, or use separate columns.